# Is there a formal definition of "data structure"?

Tags: data-structures

Data structure is a term that I've heard use I think only somewhat informally in software engineering. Is there a formal definition of it in CS?

Comment: Such terms don't usually have formal definitions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, maybe not something that corresponds exactly to the messy concept in software engineering, but maybe there is a concept in CS that captures an abstracted version of the idea?

Comment: While it is pretty unproductive to try to establish a standard formal definition for such a ubiquitous term like "data structure", there are many many formal definitions that capture varying aspects and interpretations of the term. A simple way, which object oriented programmers might appriciate, would be as a triple of (Set $S$ of possible instances, set $F$ of functions relating to $S$, and set $E$ of equations relating functions in $F$).

Answer (score 7):

No, the term doesn't have a formal definition.

You might be interested in the notion of an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), which does have a formalization.